# How do I add comments to an SVN dump file?

Tags: svn

The SVN-dump file format is described [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/dump-load-format.txt). However, I didn't find any hint on how to add a comment to an revision or node record, that is ignored when the dump gets imported.

I'm rewriting my SVN history based on the dump and I want to comment some of these rewrite actions for documentation purposes in order to document in the dump what I have done.

I tried to add some comments like this

```
## some hint on my manual manipulations
## should be written here

Revision-number: 234
Prop-content-length: 97
Content-length: 97
```

but this leads to an `svnadmin: E140001: Dump stream contains a malformed header (with no ':') at '## some hint on my m'` error.

Is it possible to add comment lines to SVN dumps?

Comment: "For documentation purposes" -- Why do you need to modify the dump file in order to document what you've done with this particular dump? I'm assuming since you're doing this dump to begin with, you're either A) filtering out some revisions and only getting the ones you want or B) relocating the repository (or both). Once the dump file is `svn load`-ed into your new repository, the file becomes rather obsolete. Not sure what comments are going to achieve here.

Comment: @Chris I relocate and merge some projects in my SVN dump. I want to comment individual revisions that I have modify manually, in order to explain why these manual modifications are necessary.If I make some mistakes and we discover them in a couple of weeks I want to remember what I have done in the dump and why.